# Is it possible to add certain parts of code depending on whether a header file is defined or not in C?

Tags: c, header-files

I'm writing code that depends on whether or not a header file is included.  If the file is included, I want certain added functionality.  Is there any way to do this, perhaps with an #if?  Using C btw

Comment: Check out using define and ifdef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `#define` a symbol in that header and use `#ifdef` later on.

```
header.h
#define HAVE_IPV6

some_file.c
#ifdef HAVE_IPV6
/* code */
#endif
```

Comment: There is also the problem of using the #include.  My program is not aware of whether the header exists or not, so I need to wrap the #include in some sort of check, otherwise I get an error when it isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

A technique commonly used with C headers is called *include guards*. The primary purpose is to prevent multiple-inclusion of header files, but they can also be used to address your need.

Include guards involve testing and conditionally setting a preprocessor constant within each header in your project, that is unique to a particular header file. To achieve this each header gets wrapped within an `#ifndef/#endif` block.

Example:

**MyHeader1.h**

```
 #ifndef MY_HEADER_1_H
 #define MY_HEADER_1_H

 // header file contents...

 #endif   // MY_HEADER_1_H
```

**MyHeader2.h**

```
 #ifndef MY_HEADER_2_H
 #define MY_HEADER_2_H

 // header file contents...

 #endif   // MY_HEADER_2_H
```

In your case, you can now test elsewhere in your code for the inclusion of any particular header file, e.g. `#ifdef MY_HEADER_1_H`